# ¿Agregar una fila a un dataframe con las sumas de algunas columnas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo el siguiente DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Inter1': {0: pd.Interval(1.0, 2.0, closed='left'),
                                  1: pd.Interval(2.0, 3.0, closed='left')},
                       'Inter2': {0: pd.Interval(1.0, 2.0, closed='both'),
                                  1: pd.Interval(2.0, 3.0, closed='both')},
                       'Inter3': {0: pd.Interval(1.0, 2.0, closed='both'),
                                  1: pd.Interval(2.0, 3.0, closed='both')},
                       'Xi': {0: 1, 1: 2},
                       'Fi': {0: 3, 1: 4}})

       Inter1      Inter2      Inter3  Xi  Fi
0  [1.0, 2.0)  [1.0, 2.0]  [1.0, 2.0]   1   3
1  [2.0, 3.0)  [2.0, 3.0]  [2.0, 3.0]   2   4
```

Quiero agregar una fila al final que muestre la suma de las columnas 'Xi' y 'Fi'.

Al probar con la siguiente línea:

```
df.append(df[list(df.columns)[3::]].sum(), ignore_index=True)
```

obtengo este error:

```
ValueError: Intervals must all be closed on the same side.
```

Comment: no será que quieres agregar una columna? Si agregas una fila dará error por que el tamaño no coincide

Comment: He visto, que se puede asignar un valor NaN a las columnas que no coincidan

Comment: Pues si pero no le veo mucho sentido :/

Comment: Te sugiero que pienses mejor lo que deseas hacer y que pruebes `df["Xi+Fi"] = df["Xi"]+df["Fi"]`

Comment: Muchas gracias, seguiré buscando .

Comment: `df.loc[len(df)+1, "Xi":"Fi"] = df.loc[:,"Xi":"Fi"].sum()`

Comment: Con Python 3.8 y pandas 1.3.4 no logro reproducir el error, y de hecho agrega la fila correctamente, de cualquier forma prueba con el código de abulafia